# Image validation using the JavascriptExecutor always return 'false' even when image is loaded

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to validate an Image loaded in the webpage using Selenium. Below is the line I use for the same.
The 'ImagePresent' always return 'false' even though it is able to capture and print the image's attribute value from the last line.

```
 WebElement Imglogo = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//img[@src='Images/Logo.png']"));

    Boolean ImagePresent = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript(
                    "return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0",
                    Imglogo);
    System.out.println("The boolean value of ImagePresent: "+ImagePresent); //returns false
    System.out.println("Image Attribute: "+Imglogo.getAttribute("src")); //prints the full path
```

Comment: I don't know selenium, so this might be completely useless - but is there any chance that you're doing your evaluation before the page loads?  Is there a way to attach to the `.load` event for the image element and do your evaluations when that fires?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to be too fancy here. You don't really need JSE in this case. You can just use `.getAtribute("naturalWidth")` and compare the expected return.

```
WebElement Imglogo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='Images/Logo.png']"));
System.out.println(Imglogo.getAttribute("naturalWidth"));
System.out.println(Imglogo.getAttribute("naturalWidth").equals("0"));
```

... and so on.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But it still returns false.

Comment: What specific code did you try that returned false?